# Reading barcode in specific text box without setting any focus in c#?

Tags: asp.net, barcode

How to display barcode in specific textbox without using any focus.
if i read data using barcode reader, data should displayed in specific textbox.

Comment: answer depends upon the actual logic implemented. Please provide some code and what do you mean by read data from some other textbox? barcode dosen't do that..dose it in your case?

Answer (score 0):

You may use Serial Port class with DataReceive event. When ever data is received, fill that data in the textbox.

```
SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM1"); //give your barcode serial port 
mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
mySerialPort.Open();

private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender,SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
        txtBoxName.Text = indata;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a javascript function listening to window.keypress event and identifying a barcode sequence, like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.currentBarcodeSequence = "";
    document.lastKeypress = new Date();
    var monitorBarcodes = function(e){
        //sequenceLimitMs should be set as low as possible to prevent capture of human keyed numbers.
        //200 allow testing without a barcode scanner, you could try a value of 50 with a scanner.
        var sequenceLimitMs = 200;
        var now = new Date();
        var elapsed = now - document.lastKeypress;
        document.lastKeypress = now;
        if(e.charCode >= 48 && e.charCode <= 57){
            //pressed key is a number
            if(elapsed < sequenceLimitMs || document.currentBarcodeSequence === ""){
                //event is part of a barcode sequence
                document.currentBarcodeSequence += (e.charCode - 48);

                if(document.currentBarcodeSequence.length > 1){
                    clearTimeout(document.printBarcodeTimeout);
                    document.printBarcodeTimeout = setTimeout("setBarcode()", sequenceLimitMs+10);
                }
            } else {
                document.currentBarcodeSequence = "" + (e.charCode - 48);
                clearTimeout(document.printBarcodeTimeout);
            }
        } else {
            document.currentBarcodeSequence = "";
            clearTimeout(document.printBarcodeTimeout);
        }
    }
    var setBarcode = function(){
        var barcodeInput = document.getElementById("barcode");
        barcodeInput.value = document.currentBarcodeSequence;
    }

    window.onkeypress = monitorBarcodes;
</script>
<input type="text" id="barcode"></input>
<input type="text"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

Tested on Firefox, IE10, Chrome & Opera.

edit: the script works assuming that the scanner just sends a key sequence the same way a keyboard would do.